# I'm looking for a proof for the Euler Characteristic of non-orientable surfaces, $χ=2−k$

Tags: general-topology, non-orientable-surfaces

Unfortunately my notes only cover the proof up to orientable surfaces, i.e., $χ=2−2g$, where $g$ is the **genus**. I would like to get some guidance on where to search for this proof. I have tried looking it up on Topological Graph Theory, by J. L. Gross and T. W. Tucker, but could not find it anywhere.

I have found some questions on this site asking about this, but they make reference to homology theory or something called cellularisation, which I have no idea of.

Edit: Explanation of the terms
Here, $χ= n - m + f$ where $n$ is the number of vertices, $m$ the number of edges, and $f$ the number of faces.
$k$ is the genus of the non-orientable surface.

Comment: What definition of Euler characteristic are you starting from? There are two major definitions of Euler characteristic (and a theorem which says they are equivalent). The first definition makes reference to homology theory. The other makes reference to a CW complex structure or one of its special cases: a triangulation; a delta complex structure; or, as you mention, a cellulation. From the wording of your question, though, you seem to have some other definition of Euler characteristic in mind. You should include your definition in your post, else your question is difficult to answer.

Comment: Oh my... Well, the left hand side of Euler's formula?

Comment: That is, $n - m + f$, where $n$ is the vertices, etc

Comment: Okay good, that tells me that you know more about cellularisations than you let on: $n$ is the number of vertices also known as 0-cells; $m$ is the number of edges also known as 1-cells; and $f$ is the number of faces also known as 2-cells.

Comment: But now there's another missing element: I don't know what $k$ means to you. In particular, I don't know what you know about nonorientable surfaces. For example, have you seen, and can you describe, a particular construction of the nonorientable surfaces that you are asking about?

Comment: @LeeMosher Oh I see, we didn't call them cells. For me, $k$ is the genus of the non-orientable surface, or the number of "handles" attached to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108424/discussion-between-threnody-and-lee-mosher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to construct a single cell decomposition of the nonorientable surface of genus $k$ --- meaning a decomposition into vertices, edges and faces --- count the number $n$ of vertices, $m$ of edges, and $f$ of faces, compute $n-m+f$, and verify that the result is $2-k$.

Now, there are many, many, many different cell decompositions, and you only need one, because *they all give the same answer*. If you ever wonder why that's true, that's what you need homology to prove. But, setting that aside, all you need is one decomposition.

The easiest cell decomposition that I know of comes from gluing the sides of a $2k$ sided polygon in the pattern $a_1a_1a_2a_2a_3a_3....a_ka_k$. One checks that all vertices are identified to a single vertex so $n=1$, the $2k$ sides are identified to $k$ edges so $m=k$, and the interior of the polygon gives a single face so $f=1$, hence $n-m+f=2-k$.

I encourage you to try to find your own cell decomposition, count, and compute.